# How to Prove $0 \neq 1$ in Type Theory

Tags: type-theory

We define a type $\mathbb{N}$, an element $0: \mathbb{N}$, and a function $\operatorname{succ}:\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$.  I would like to prove that $0 \neq \operatorname{succ}(0)$.  So, I have to construct a function $(0 = \operatorname{succ}(0)) \to \emptyset$.  If $p: 0 = \operatorname{succ}(0)$, I don't see what to do with it.  Based on $p$, I can prove 
$$
\prod_{x:\mathbb{N}} x = \operatorname{succ}(x).
$$
But, I don't see how that's useful.

Comment: Which type theory?

Comment: @AsafKaragila Martin-Lof, from the Homotopy Type Theory book.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The main idea behind this type of proof that $a = b \rightarrow \emptyset$ is to use a $\mathbb{N}$-indexed family of types $P$ such that:

- $P(a)$ is trivially inhabited (e.g. the unit type)
- $P(b)$ is $\emptyset$

Then you can transport a proof of $P(a)$ along the proof of equality $a = b$ to get a proof of $\emptyset$.

In the setting of the interactive theorem prover Coq, this proof style is explained in details (including for more complex examples) in Monin's [Proof Trick: Small Inversions](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/inria-00489412/).